# Custom C# Web Browser cannot support javascript

Tags: c#, web, browser

I'm creating a web browser that has an automatic loading of specific web pages, but the problem is that the browser that i created using c# in visual studio wont load javascipt, the browser that i created only load html file, but don't support java script. can anyone help me on how to add some functionality on my custom web browser that will support javascript.

Comment: are you working with web browser control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebKit DotNet is the best port of WebKit powerful browser engine into DotNetFramework.

It has nice and easy tutorials and properties and methods to customize.

It has JavaScript activated by default.

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ is the official website.

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php is where you can find the basic tutorial

Comment: Do not use IE,IE is really awful and old browser.When you use the web browser control;your IE version is based on the version of IE the user has on his computer.But if you use WebKit,You will have the latest version of a WebKit on any supported Operating System.

Comment: + When the user removed IE, you come into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Webbrowser control is really crappy. I'm assuming you're trying to scape some kind of website. For this use `HttpWebRequest` instead.

If you`re trying create your own webbrowser: don't, or use Webkit or Gecko instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using the webbrowser control you will have to enable JavaScript in your Internet Explorer settings, because the webbrowser control *is* the Internet Explorer or at least the engine of it. IE has local JavaScript disabled by default, so this could be your problem. As user @user3855678 said I would recommend using Webkit etc too.

Comment: thanks i will try it, and see if this could help me.